# Adding/removing class dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, class, menu, onclick

Hello I have a menu and I would like to remove the class active an add it to the element that I click....that was my idea but it is not working so well...

```
<div id="header2">
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li id="menu_1" onclick="abrirPag('home.html')">Home</li>
                    <li id="menu_2" onclick="abrirPag('calendario_2014.html')">Calendário</li>
                    <li id="menu_3" onclick="abrirPag('classificacao_2014.html')">Classificação</li>
                    <li id="menu_4" onclick="abrirPag('equipes_2014.html')">Equipes</li>
                    <li id="menu_5" onclick="abrirPag('recordes.html')">Recordes</li>
                    <li id="menu_6" onclick="abrirPag('regulamento_2014.html')">Regulamento</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Onload function to add the class active to the first item:

```
window.onload=function() {
var containermenu = document.getElementById("header2");
var navitemmenu = containermenu.querySelector(".menu ul li");
var identmenu = navitemmenu.id.split("_")[1];
navitemmenu.parentNode.setAttribute("data-current",identmenu);
navitemmenu.setAttribute("class","active");
```

Function to change the class:

```
function abrirPag(valor){
var currentmenu = this.parentNode.getAttribute("data-current");
document.getElementById("menu_" + currentmenu).removeAttribute("class");
var identmenu = this.id.split("_")[1];
this.setAttribute("class","tabActiveHeader");
this.parentNode.setAttribute("data-current",identmenu);
```

I get the following error when I click any of the elements: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getAttribute' of undefined "

Can someone help me?

Comment: @Teemu I retract my suggestion. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this`  value in an inline handler will be the `window` object instead of the element. You need to pass `this` to get it to the function.

```
<li id="menu_1" onclick="abrirPag(this, 'home.html')">Home</li>
```

Then reference it as the first element.

```
function abrirPag(elem, valor){
    var currentmenu = elem.parentNode.getAttribute("data-current");
    document.getElementById("menu_" + currentmenu).className = "";
    var identmenu = elem.id.split("_")[1];

    elem.className = "tabActiveHeader";
    elem.parentNode.setAttribute("data-current",identmenu);
}
```

I also changed it to use the `.className` property instead of `.get/setAttribute()` for getting and setting the class.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the dom classList to add remove classes

```
var element = document.getElementById("someId");
//Use add to add a class
element.classList.add("active");
//use remove to remove a class
element.classList.remove("active");
```

You will need a [polyfill](https://github.com/Raynos/DOM-shim) to use it on IE < 10 and some of the older versions of browsers.

To remove from all other menu and add to current do as cookie monster suggest and also pass the element to your function

```
function abrirPag(ele,valor){
   var current = document.getElementsByClassName("tabActiveHeader");
   if(current[0]){
      current[0].classList.remove("tabActiveHeader");
   }
   ele.classList.add("tabActiveHeader");
}
```

Comment: Couple notes. The `if(current)` will always be `true` since `gEBCN` will always return a collection. Also, the collection returned will be reindexed when you remove the class from the element that was used to match it. If there's always only one element with that class *(which means it should probably be an ID)* it'll be alright, though a `break` would be good. If there can be multiple with that class, there can be problems.

Comment: ...but +1 for `.classList` with the polyfill link.

Comment: oh didnt event think about that

Answer (score -1):

Here it's a tip: use jQuery, you'll have a much easier life:

```
$("#header2 .menu li a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var index = $("#header2 .menu li a").index(this);
    $("#header2 .menu li a").removeClass("active").parent().parent().data("current", index);
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".content").text($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Take a look at **[this Fiddle I've created](http://jsfiddle.net/EKqs7/1/)**!

Comment: Here's a tip. Don't suggest slow, bloated code libraries to solve simple issues.

Comment: Not so long ago I responded an "use-jQuery" comment with [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question)... I mean these guys asking questions here are most likely coding for living, they have schedules and boss breathing at neck, no time to learn to use a whole library, just to complete a simple task. There's an attempted solution in the post, why not just fix the errors in it, and then, maybe as a bonus, offer some totally different solution...

Comment: First of all, he's brazilian, so am I, and he's developing a new personal Soccer's website, from scratch, and I'm giving him a tip to use the most-used library for doing that, so he'll clean up a lot his code. And I didn't say "use jQuery" and nothing more, I've created a code for him, and also a Fiddle where he can play with it if he likes. It's not a simple issue, working with class attribute in pure javascript cross browser is not that simple, unfortunately. I'm a Javascript fan, and if you see my answers, I usually make pure-javascript codes to help the guys. But in a particular case (...)

Comment: But in a particular case like this, I'm suggesting him to use jQuery, cause it'll simplificate his life a lot. If someone suggested me using jQuery before, I wouldn't take so many years before using it and improving a lot my coding.

Comment: Btw, thanks for the URL, anyway, it's a nice Q/A. And btw², there are tons of solutions provided here from other guys, so just let the OP choose what fits better for him.

Comment: I can't connect nationality to this in any aspect. Also looks like you really didn't read my comment ; ). Btw. Not my downvote.

Comment: Btw³, people answering with `document.getElementsByClassName("tabActiveHeader")`, a totally non-cross browser solution won't help either.

Comment: I have no problems with downvotes @Teemu, you can downvote if you want to, and if I get 100 downvotes, there will be no problem, I'm only trying to help the guy. About not reading your comment, I did, and I answered saying that "no, he doesn't do that for living, he doesn't have a boss, he does have time to learn". About the nationality, I used this to answer, cause I can understand his Brazilian Portuguese website, and then think about the better suggestion for his problem.

Comment: Well, not my upvote either ; ), and you're right about `gEBCN()`. Where actually you got the website, it's not linked in the post nor OP's profile? About downvoting, I'm not tending to downvote anybody's answers/questions, you can see it in my profile, during two years under 10% of my voting are downvotes. Just mentioned about it, in the case you'd change your answer, and if the downvote won't be removed, you can't blame me : ).

Comment: Thanks for your answer too Buzinas!!! It is actually a go kart website ^^ (we don't like only soccer/football in brazil)!! I appreciate your answer, I'm not an expert so I've just learned javascript and don't know much about jquery yet, but your example is really good to follow and to learn a bit!!! Thanks again

Comment: Kart's much better =D I run at least once a week!

Comment: _"a totally non-cross browser solution"_ gEBCN is supported on all modern browsers, and for those that do not have native support there are polyfills